# Can I use Ubuntu's default Python 2.7 with Anaconda?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my system and installed Anaconda as my default Python distribution with v3.5. I would like to have both v2.7 and v3.5 managed by `conda`, but it seems that in order to do so I need to create a separate environment for v2.7.

I am new to Ubuntu and Anaconda, but if I understand correctly, creating this separate `conda` environment for v2.7 actually installs this version over again in the `env` directory and ignores the native Python 2.7 installation that comes in Ubuntu.

Is there any way to leverage the native installation for use with Anaconda or am I stuck installing it in two separate locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create environments for each:

From your terminal:

```
$ conda create -n py2 python=2

$ conda create -n py3 python=3
```

Then you just activate the appropriate environment, where you can install additional packages.

```
$ source activate py3
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I am concerned about creating a redundant installation of Python 2.7 when I create a new environment for it. I want to leverage the native Ubuntu Python for the second environment.

Comment: You don't use the native Ubuntu Python. You get an Anaconda build (e.g. Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) ).   This is one of the reasons why you don't have to worry about accidentally trashing your OS version.

Comment: Please bear with me, but does that mean that there is no option to use the native Ubuntu build with Anaconda and I have to use whatever build Anaconda installs in its installation directory?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that is correct.  http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html